# Opening files from cygwin home in windows applications

Tags: cygwin

I remember that when I first installed cygwin I could open files form my home directory using Windows applications. For example, I had Emacs installed in Windows and I could just do `runemacs ~/some_file.txt`. I had run out of space and had to move my cygwin installation to a different drive. Ever since then, I seem to have mucked up my installation and I can't use Windows applications like this anymore.

I have removed cygwin completely and re-installed it in C:\cygwin as before, but the problem remains.

I see that for some reason `~` gets expanded to `C:\home\Tudor` instead of `C:\cygwin\home\Tudor`.

Does anyone know how I could get this to work again?

Comment: That's odd, I wouldn't expect `~` to refer to your home directory when used in a non-Cygwin application (though I've never tried it myself). Only Cygwin would know how to expand `~`, and ordinary Windows applications aren't aware of Cygwin. Are you sure your Emacs isn't a Cygwin application? If nothing else, you could probably set a Windows environment variable and refer to `%H%/some_file.txt`.

Comment: If I just open Emacs in Windows and open `~` from there, then it takes  me to `C:\Users\Tudor`. I'm guessing the expansion of `~` in Cygwin was done before Emacs started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-Cygwin Windows applications are not aware of your Cygwin root or home directory.

Emacs is a special case. It was originally developed on UNIX, and it uses UNIX-like syntax for some things.

According to your latest comment, Emacs expands `~` to `C:\Users\Tudor`. That's your *Windows* home directory, not your Cygwin home directory.

You can also install a Cygwin version of Emacs, which, like any Cygwin application, will expand `~` to your Cygwin home directory.

If you invoke a Windows application from a Cygwin shell, then the shell, *not* the Windows application, will expand `~` to your Cygwin home directory, expressed in Cgywin syntax. For example, assuming `runemacs` is a non-Cygwin application, if I run:

```
bash$ runemacs ~
```

then the shell expands the `~`, so it's equivalent to (assuming my user name is `Tudor`):

```
bash$ runemacs /home/Tudor
```

`runemacs` will probably treat `/home/Tudor` as equivalent to `\home\Tudor`, which would be equivalent to `C:\home\Tudor` if the current drive is `C:`.

If you type <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd> from within Emacs to open a file, then Emacs will interpret `~` according to whatever rules it follows internally; those rules aren't likely to recognize Cygwin unless you're running a Cygwin version of Emacs *or* Emacs itself has some special-case code to handle Cygwin paths.

Comment: Emacs is a special case for sure. If I open it in Windows it will expand `~` to my Windows home. If I open it in Cygwin `~` will expand to my cygwin home. By open in Cygwin I mean starting the windows application from a Cygwin shell and not the Cygwin Emacs version. I still think that Cygwin might expand `~` in file paths passed as arguments to windows applications and that is's a configuration issue (as it worked in the past).

Comment: @Tudor: If you run a command from the Cygwin bash shell, the shell will expand `~` to the Cygwin-style path of your Cygwin home directory. A Windows application will likely interpret that path incorrectly. See my updated answer.